# Firebase Is Not Throwing The True Error with useSignInWithEmailAndPassword || React Web App Project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, react-typescript

I am trying to throw an error when an email is in use using typescript, firebase and react. I have successfully registered an account, however when I type the same email with another password, signInWithEmailAndPassword does not throw any errors, and it is worrying. My code is the following:

```
import { AuthModalState } from '@/atoms/authModalAtom';
import { Input, Button, Flex, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSetRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import {useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword, useSignInWithEmailAndPassword} from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import { auth } from '@/firebase/clientApp';
import 'firebase/auth';

const SignUp:React.FC = () => {
    
    const setAuthModalState = useSetRecoilState(AuthModalState)
    const [signUpForm, setSignUpForm] = useState({
        email:"",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
    })
    const [notMatchedError,setNotMatchedError] = useState("")
    const [alreadyInUseError,setAlreadyInUseError] = useState("")
    
    const [
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
        user,
        loading,
        userError,
      ] = useCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth);
    const [
        signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        signInError,
        signInLoading
    ] = useSignInWithEmailAndPassword(auth)
    
    
          
    
    const onSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        setNotMatchedError("");
        setAlreadyInUseError("");
        
        

        if (signUpForm.password != signUpForm.confirmPassword) {
            setNotMatchedError("Passwords do not match.")
        }else{
            signInWithEmailAndPassword(signUpForm.email, signUpForm.password)
            .then(function(){
                setAlreadyInUseError("What is wrong with this app?")
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
                if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                    setAlreadyInUseError("Email already in use.")
                } else {
                    setAlreadyInUseError(errorMessage)
                }
                console.log(error);
            });
```

It always gives "What is wrong with this app?" which is inside the .then(), any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy because of the useSignInWithEmailAndPassword constants above. Just create a new file and write every message like this:

```
export const FIREBASE_ERRORS = {
    
  "Firebase: Error (auth/email-already-in-use).":
    "A user with that email already exists",}
```

Then import and use it like this:

````
 {userError && (
                <Text textAlign= "center" color = "#FF8080" fontSize="10pt">{FIREBASE_ERRORS[userError.message as keyof typeof FIREBASE_ERRORS]}</Text>
            )
            }```
````